# yotpo review show in tabs - M2

Tags: magento2, tabs, product-review

Can anyone help me to show yotpo review into tabs at product details page?

I have try with this script in **catalog_product_view.xml** file, It's showing magento's review but i want to show yotpo review.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="review" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Reviews</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">30</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

Comment: Delete current review tab, create new tab and call yotpo's phtml inside new tab or move content into newly created tab using xml

Comment: not able to found yotpo's phtml block and phtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, yotpo fetches review content from remote server and displays it on the product page. 
How about adding

```
<?= $this->helper('Yotpo\Yotpo\Helper\Data')->showWidget($block) ?>
```

to the theme according to
https://support.yotpo.com/en/article/setting-up-yotpo-on-magento-v22-and-above